# Kruskal's Algorithm with disconnected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I am not sure how to implement Kruskal's algorithm when the graph has multiple connected components

From my understanding of Kruskal's algorithm, it repeatedly adds the minimal edge to a set. Then when all the edges are checked, it returns the set of edges that makes the most.

However, what if my graph is disconnected? Say I have:

```
A - B - C - D

E - F
```

And say the Cost( A - B ) = Cost( E - F ) = 1, and the rest of the edges are greater than 1

When I run Kruskal, I would get the all the edge's costs, but I want to get the cost of EACH of the connected component so I do an average of minimal cost over all the connected component.

Comment: How is this a programming question?  You might have better luck on another StackExchange site.

Comment: Kruskal will give you a minimal spanning forest. If you want the cost of a single tree in that forest, just add it up. What's the problem?

Comment: I need to take the average of each of the forest.

Comment: Your language is unclear. Suppose `cost(B-C)` is 2 and `cost(C-D)` is 6. Now show us what you want to calculate.

Comment: Kruskal's will give you a minimum spanning forest in that case. Just find the connected components before or after running Kruskal, it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Kruskal's algorithm works like so:

It will *add* (union) edges one by one, and specialized in maintaining disjoint sets.

It sounds like you are looking to have a *Minimum Spanning Tree* for each set of *connected vertices* (so you can then play around with those separate trees' aggregated, minimum weighted costs), yes?

So, you are correct in choosing Kruskal over Prim (the latter of which would not run on a disconnected graph).

Kruskal will run just fine on your disconnected graph; it will find a *minimum spanning tree* for *each connected component*.

"For graphs that are not connected Kruskal’s algorithm returns a forest of
spanning trees— one for each component of the graph." [(a great paper on Spanning Trees by Michael P. Fourman— a Prof. of CS at University of Edinburgh)](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/mfourman/teaching/mlCourse/notes/L14.pdf)

Alternatively, you could run Prim's on each subgraph that contains only connected components.

Best of luck (if you haven't already long figured out your problem).

[Kruskal's Algorithm Pseudo-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9liK9.png)